# Enveloping signatures with XadesBes timestamped

Tags: java, xml, xades4j

I am trying to pass `<NextMsg ID="Edoc">2019-09-20T14:57:46</NextMsg>` to a function and sign it with digital signature wrapped in root `<EDoc></Edoc>` tag

This is an expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDoc>
    <NextMsg ID="Edoc">2019-09-20T14:57:46</NextMsg>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="DS_A2B2112853C1478C8860CB8DC6FA23D2">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>op0/fC+H5/0h7AGdUiEaNnNzd9WXs3VDouQQhRk8XgU=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#SP_A2B2112853C1478C8860CB8DC6FA23D2" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#SignedProperties">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>Kv75qkIImVnf9H7PZV+1er1n8YIBY5yRGXdpWSUIAX4=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>=sign-value=</SignatureValue>
        <ds:Object xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <QualifyingPropertiesReference URI="http://www.test.com"/>
            <QualifyingProperties Target="#DS_A2B2112853C1478C8860CB8DC6FA23D2">
                <SignedProperties Id="SP_A2B2112853C1478C8860CB8DC6FA23D2">
                    <SignedSignatureProperties>
                        <SigningTime>2019-09-20T14:57:48+03:00</SigningTime>
                        <SigningCertificate>
                            <Cert>
                                <CertDigest>
                                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <DigestValue>woG3fsImDUeqxznickzLkpeY9R4=</DigestValue>
                                </CertDigest>
                                <IssuerSerial>
                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>XXX</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>YYY</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                </IssuerSerial>
                            </Cert>
                        </SigningCertificate>
                        <SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                            <SignaturePolicyImplied/>
                        </SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                    </SignedSignatureProperties>
                </SignedProperties>
            </QualifyingProperties>
        </ds:Object>
    </Signature>
</EDoc>
```

my actual function is this:

```
    public static String getSignatureXadesTBes(String xmlrequest, PrivateKey pk, X509Certificate cert) throws
javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException, org.xml.sax.SAXException, java.io.FileNotFoundException,
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException, javax.xml.transform.TransformerException,
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException, java.io.IOException, java.security.KeyStoreException,
xades4j.XAdES4jException
{

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlrequest));
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);

    Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
    DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(elem);

    KeyingDataProvider keyingProvider = new DirectKeyingDataProvider(cert, pk);

    DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference("")
                    .withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());

    SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects().withSignedDataObject(obj);

    XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesTSigningProfile(keyingProvider);

p.withTimeStampTokenProvider(
  new DefaultTimeStampTokenProvider(
            new DefaultMessageDigestProvider()
        ));

    BasicSignatureOptionsProvider sop = new DefaultBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(false, false, false);
    p.withBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(sop);

    AlgorithmsProviderEx ap = new DefaultAlgorithmsProviderEx() {

            @Override
            public String getDigestAlgorithmForDataObjsReferences() {
                return MessageDigestAlgorithm.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256;
            }

            @Override
            public String getDigestAlgorithmForReferenceProperties() {
                return MessageDigestAlgorithm.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1;
            }

            @Override
            public Algorithm getSignatureAlgorithm(String keyAlgorithmName) throws UnsupportedAlgorithmException {
                return new GenericAlgorithm(XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
            }
    };

    p.withAlgorithmsProviderEx(ap);

    XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

    XadesSignatureResult result = signer.sign(dataObjs, elem);
    XMLSignature signature = result.getSignature();
    Document docs = signature.getDocument();

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("..\\cfgFiles\\out_xades.xml");
    XMLUtils.outputDOM(doc, os);
}
```

But it results in

```
<NextMsg Id="Edoc">2019-09-20T14:57:46<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690-ref0" URI="">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>8t2TvSeJ1iz7XTyYV7VHYJtTRLrbx/72Z35rkyEBGLs=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690-signedprops">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>t6UMqsiPZoXoxf7wOOg+beyztdEjD4u5GjWMrlyS1nI=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690-sigvalue">
STjMdaycvdWLWYVMd2bCvxjIUxoI0/aOWFshihQ8lurmLnmAMlQGAt7yzYMcrywV/7t58Eip+xOp&#xD;
fuU+S7UsB9b9cS9iy1m0U5fy9pGdud5HqKgDEeNjx//kAGKSZQP232PVTlZ5i+QB1kfotpfrZp6h&#xD;
FAtwJGd4fijdJ5JuAYI=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:Object>
            <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690">
                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-24f667da-ced7-4727-b107-0daa2be5b690-signedprops">
                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                        <xades:SigningTime>2019-09-20T20:21:33.956+03:00</xades:SigningTime>
                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                            <xades:Cert>
                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>woG3fsImDUeqxznickzLkpeY9R4=</ds:DigestValue>
                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>cn=LB-LITAS-CA,ou=MSD,o=Lietuvos bankas,l=Vilnius,c=LT</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>105704079740755226136574</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                            </xades:Cert>
                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                </xades:SignedProperties>
                <xades:UnsignedProperties>
                    <xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties>
                        <xades:SignatureTimeStamp>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

                        </xades:SignatureTimeStamp>
                    </xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties>
                </xades:UnsignedProperties>
            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
        </ds:Object>
    </ds:Signature>
</NextMsg>
```

I think I messed up enveloping of xades4j or parameters passed. I dont really want Signature inside the element being signed - I want signature to be included along it like in an above expected structure. Could somebody point me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XadesSigner.sign` will add the signature as a child of the supplied element. Since you say you're passing `<NextMsg>...` in the string parameter, the output is as it should be.

To reproduce the output you intended, you should probably pass `<tDoc><NextMsg>...` and pass the document node to the `sign` method (`<tDoc`), so that the signature is appended to it. If you need more control, you can use [the `sign` overload](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.5.0/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSigner.html#sign(xades4j.production.SignedDataObjects,%20org.w3c.dom.Node,%20xades4j.production.XadesSigner.SignatureAppendingStrategy)) that allows to specify a different way of attaching the signature to the document (e.g. `SignatureAppendingStrategies.lastChild`)

Side note: you probably want to make the document builder factory namespace aware.

Comment: I separated root and child element, then passed root to XadesSigner.sign and it worked. IMO The name of the function `sign` probably should be renamed to `includeSignatureTo`